# Background Image Wont Re-size When Changing Browser Size

Tags: html, css

I've been fiddling with my background image in CSS for a couple hours now and have tried searching through articles to find a solution but still have nothing. I'm trying to make my background image fit the screen no matter what the browser size.

At first I was using this CSS code which seemed to be working:

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But then when I re-sized the browser this happened: http://prntscr.com/j1d4kv

I then went and found another solution that said I should put the background image in the html tag, which i tried:

```
html {
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This fixed the issue of the background image not fitting to the bottom when the browser size changed, but then I had this issue when I was full screened: http://prntscr.com/j1d742 It left a gap on the right side!

Comment: `background-position: fixed;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your `body` doesn't reach the full height of the browser window, if it doesn't have much content. Add this to correct that:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked! I tried it first with the body tag but it wasn't working and instead did the html tag along with the other code I had in and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You want to add,
background-attachment: fixed;

Here's an example: https://embed.plnkr.co/3Y7O1TQa8ssPQKVq0tCW/